# Checking the length of a string provided

Tags: sybase, check-constraint

I'm trying to define a domain which will allow to pass only 6 chars strings. I'm declaring it in a following way:

```
create domain aircrafts_reg_nos as char(6)
check(length(@value) = 6)
```

But this doesn't seem to catch strings which are longer than 6 chars. Is there a way to enforce it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*length* is not a Sybase SQL function.  To find the length of a character field, use *char_length*.  So your code should probably look something like this.

```
create domain aircrafts_reg_nos as char(6)
check(char_length(@value) = 6)
```

Also, try to do a little more research to make sure you are using the right function names in your code.